# Why I can't get file size and tmp_name

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I want to get size and tmp_name of selected file but I am getting an error **UNEXPECTED T_VARIABLE**

HTML:

```
File: <input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file">
```

PHP:

```
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

and when I try to `echo $size` it dont do anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: what you posted as an error for code you included, does not support themselves. And what's the full error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing `form` and if not you maybe missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form`